# Create 2D array from two JSON calls, then scramble it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Basically what I have so far is two JSON calls:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (combined) {
  $.each(combined.data.children, function (i, data) {
    titles.push(data.data.title);
    solutions.push(data.data.subreddit);
  });
})
.done(function () {
  $.getJSON(url2, function (combined) {
    $.each(combined.data.children, function (i, data) {
      titles.push(data.data.title);
      solutions.push(data.data.subreddit);
    });
  })
  .done(function () {
    // Done
  }
})
```

I want to have `titles` and `solutions` combined into a 2D array, but every answer I find online doesn't seem to work with my `$.each()` statements. After combining the two, I want to scramble it so it is in a random order. All the scrambling scripts I find seem to not work with 2D arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, took some time but all is now well.

```
$.getJSON(url1, function (result0) {
  $.each(result0.data.children, function (i, data) {
    tisol[i][0] = (data.data.title);
    tisol[i][1] = (data.data.subreddit).toLowerCase();
  });
})
.done(function () {
  $.getJSON(url2, function (result1) {
    $.each(result1.data.children, function (i, data) {
      i = i + 5;
        tisol[i][0] = (data.data.title);
        tisol[i][1] = (data.data.subreddit).toLowerCase();
    });
  })
  .done(function () {
    tisol = shuffleArray(tisol);
    for (i = 0; i < tisol.length; i++) {
      // Print results
    }
  })
  .fail(function () {
    // Fail
  });
})
.fail(function () {
   // Fail
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing the `/s` means sarcasm.  Is this true?

Comment: Yep, kinda got a bit annoyed, but probably better for me for figuring it out. Gonna remove the `/s` bit now lol

Comment: If you didn't, I would have.  That kind of thing isn't really welcome here.  However, maybe I'm preaching here, but not getting an answer doesn't immediately mean 20 people saw your question, and chose not to help you.  It could mean of the 20 people, no one knew _how_ to help you.  It's also only been about a day, not everything is instant.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's been a long day and I'm tired. Sorry about that.